# how to add confirmation fields to mysql table creation

Tags: android, mysql

I am following a tutorial on how to make table with mysql for android studio app
this is the code to create table

```
create table users(
id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
name varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(100) not null unique,
encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
salt varchar(10) not null,
created_at datetime,
updated_at datetime null
);
```

but the form in this tutorial only has:

```
name
email
password
```

while my form has:

```
email
confirm email
name
password
confirm password
referral code
```

how do i add the confirmation fields,e.g confirm password fields to mysql create table

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: okay what do you suggest i do?

Comment: Use a function such as `password_hash`/`password_verify` `PBKDF2` or `Bcrypt` with about a 100ms duration.

Comment: sorry, im not so saavy with sql, where should that function go?

Answer (score 2):

Do not add confirm field in database as it would be against DRY(Do Not Repeat YourSelf) Because if adding Two column contain same value would wastage of storage. You can do validation at android side. This would be good option than adding field in database

Answer (score 2):

On Account creation:

1. Validate the fields
2. Comapre the password and confirmation fields
3. Run the password through a password derivation function such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` or `Bcrypt` depending on the language you are using.
4. Put the password derivation in the password field of the DB

On login:

1. Retrive the account information from the DB using the userID, (name?)

if using `password_hash`/`password_verify`

2. Call `password_verify` withthe presented password and the password value from the DB

else

2. Run the password through the password derivation function used above
3. Compare the derived password to the value in the DB

Note: Do not add a `confirm password` or `confirm email` field to the DB, just use them to verify the submission.