# Manually encrypt user password in Symfony php

Tags: php, symfony, encryption, passwords

I have a need to manually encrypt the password in the same way [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) does it.

```
$user->setPlainPassword($password);
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

This is application code that saves the user password. But it is obviously encrypted (not plain as method says).

How can I manually get the same result for given password?

EDIT1:

The problem is that I want to authenticate user manually in users controller code. I have readable username and password that comes as parameters. I want to return 401 if they to not exist in database.

Comment: What are ypou using the password for?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#using-password-encoders

Comment: @zaph I need the password to compare it with the one in database. Basically I need to authenticate user manually in php code.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your question title "Manually encrypt user password in Symfony php" to the google. And you won't believe - the first item is exactly what you want.

Comment: You do not need the password you need a password verifier. A password verifier is a representation of the password that can not be reversed to recover the password. On creation the password is run through the verifier and the result saved. On verification the password to e verified is again run through the verifier and the result compared to the saved verifier. For php there is a simple and secure pair of methods: `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. See passwsord [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) & [verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `ehash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: See this answer for more information on handlinging [password verification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44369965/451475)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this in your controller action:

```
$encoder = $this->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($userClass);
$encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($plainPassword);
```

Comment: You can use `UserPasswordEncoderInterface` class too: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/password_encoding.html

Answer (score 28):

Symfony comes with a useful command to encode a password the same way it does:

```
bin/console security:encode-password 'your_plain_password' 'AppBundle\Entity\YourUserClass'
```

Comment: @eomeroff you could check the `security:encode-password` source to see how they do it. Seriously, don't be that lazy.

Comment: @eomeroff Get an IDE to quickly navigate through the code. For Symfony we mainly used PHPStorm.

Comment: Or just look in the symfony console for the possible commands, Simple as bonjour ;)

Answer (score 14):

In newer Symfony versions (5.3+) you can do it by running CLI command:

```sh
bin/console security:hash-password
```